# select random image from folder to display in picturebox, vb.net

Tags: vb.net, random, png

I have a picture box which reads in an image from a folder to display, instead of having the usual boring image I thought it may be nice to have a number of images in the folder and let my vb.net program randomly pick one out to use.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
Public Function GetRandomImageFilePath(ByVal folderPath As String) As String
    Dim files() As String = Directory.GetFiles(folderPath, "*.png")
    Dim random As Random = New Random()
    Return files(random.Next(0, files.Length - 1))
End Function
```

FYI, if you are going to call it multiple times, it would be better to create `random` once as a private member of the class so that it doesn't reseed the random number generation every time it's called.

Comment: multiple in which way, this program consists of only one form?

Comment: I'm just saying, if you are going to call this method multiple times, especially in quick succession, it would be good to move the `Dim random As Random = New Random()` line up to the form level, but if the form only ever calls it once, it's not necessary.  Either way it will work fine.  It's just it will be slightly less efficient and less random.  It's just good practice in general when dealing with random numbers to only seed once, when possible.  For your purposes, though, I don't think it's necessary.