# How do you randomize pictures being drawn from a folder in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, random, picturebox

How do you randomize pictures being drawn from a folder to be loaded in a picturebox in VB.NET? I'm drawing a single picture at regular intervals from a folder to a picturebox. I would like to know how to randomize the selection of the picture from the folder. The kicker is that this folder occasionally grows by a few picture files, so the obvious method of creating a variable for each initial file won't work. I'm very new to programming so example code would be much appreciated.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

```
    Dim rnd As New Random
    Dim alljpgs() As String = IO.Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.jpg", IO.SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
    Dim jpg As New Bitmap(alljpgs(rnd.Next(0, alljpgs.Count - 1)))
    PictureBox1.Image = jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a similar question has been posted, and answered, here: [select random image from folder to display in picturebox, vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10916491/select-random-image-from-folder-to-display-in-picturebox-vb-net)

Comment: Yea I saw that. I wish I knew how that code worked in context though.

Comment: In context? The three lines are 

1. get all files from the folder
2. create a random number between 0 and the number of files - 1
3. get the file that is in that "random number"th position in the file list you created in step 1.

Comment: Right that would work, but I have that kicker I mentioned. The program will be set up so new picture files are transfer into the folder I'm drawing pictures from... and I need to include these new pics when drawing a random pic. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes - if you execute the method in the other post each time you want  a new picture to display, the Directory.GetFiles call will get all files in the folder at that moment. Any new files you've added will automatically be considered as long as they are in the correct folder.